# Не запускается приложение в режиме 7.1 64Bit

Tags: xcode, ios7

Коллеги, Помогайте, не знаю куда смотреть и где искать проблему:

Имеем приложение, успешно стартующее и работающее в версии ios 7.1. Но как только я указываю "Симулятор iOS 7.1 64 bit" (или на iPhone 5S запускаю), приложение на старте вылетает:

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"deltaPrice" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}
```

Вылетает на строке:

> _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

С ошибкой: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=exc_i386_gpflt, ... ИЛИ code=1

Куда смотреть? Что делать?

Comment: Пробывали удалить приложение перед этим?

Comment: удалите приложение с симулятора и снова запустите

Comment: Это я попробовал в первую очередь :) и удалял, и чистил приложение. И удалял даже кеш по ветке Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/

Comment: пробовали проверить NSFileManager есть ли файл по урлу модели?

Comment: Ага, проверял: Был

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй в Builds Settings : Build Active Architecture Only -> NO, и из Valid Architectures удали arm64

Comment: Ага, отключив 64bit - заработало. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Удалось решить проблему "пересборкой" CoreData. Я добавил новую "базу" и перенес в нее настройки.
Проблема, видимо, в том, что проект я делал еще в 32bit и он "пронаследовался" в 64bit.